# Not Null in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
If Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1) <> "" Then
```

Is this statement right?
I want to check if the particular sheet is not equal to NULL in VBA

```
Dim x As Integer

    x = 2

Dim z As Long
Dim Myarray(1 To 9) As String

    For z = 1 To 9
        If Trim(Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1)) <> "" Then
            Myarray(z) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1)

            Debug.Print Myarray(z)
        End If
    Next z
```

This is the full code guys,

Now what i want is,I want to Check if it is empty and if it is not empty I hav to pass it .

So whaat should i mention in else statement so that it would be fine ..

Comment: What is `z` defined as? A bit more of your code would be useful please. Apart from that, are you experiencing a specific issue?

Comment: That's fine to test for a cell that contains no text (A cell value will never be NULL)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience ,Z is defined as integer .

Comment: @Gareth after giving this specific statement ,My loop is still running ,So a bit confused..

Comment: Update your question with the piece of code including the loop and we'll take a look.

Comment: Done @Gareth .PLease look into it.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to determine if any object is NULL you should use the `IsNull` function:

```
Debug.Print IsNull(Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1))
```

or

```
Debug.Print IsNull(Sheets("DealComparison"))
```

to test if a particular sheet is NULL, as your question asks.

If you want to test for a zero length string it is more efficient to test using `Len(string) = 0` than `string = ""` as strings are stored in memory with the number of characters first, followed by that number of characters and a null terminated character.  This makes the string length more readily available than testing the characters and avoids the memory allocation operations that would be involved.

```
    If Len(Trim(Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1))) = 0 Then
        Myarray(z) = Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1)

        Debug.Print Myarray(z)
    End If
```

There's an interesting review of how strings are stored in VB6/VBA [here](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c7495/How-Visual-Basic-6-Stores-Data.htm).

Answer (score 4):

That works for checking if the cell(Row z+1, Column A) on the DealComparison sheet is null or not, you could also use `VBNullString`

Such as:

```
If Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1) <> VBNullString Then
```

Comment: Do i have to use VBNullString  or " " is fine?

Comment: Either use "" or vbnullstring, they'll achieve the same result. Don't use " " (Note the space)

Answer (score 3):

Because you can have spaces in your cell sometimes those do not evaluate in the above statement. hence i always use the TRIM function as well..

`If TRIM(Sheets("DealComparison").Cells(z + 1, 1)) <> "" Then`

Answer (score 1):

Yes as long as "Z" is long integer. Hehe, funny sentence.

Comment: Sorry @Jelovac , i have no idea who has down voted it .

Comment: That was me. I am sorry. Accidentally clicked down vote (Poor aiming skill :) ). I corrected it though.